# Do multinomial and binomial tests belong to G tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I understand that [multinomial tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test) and [binomial tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) are both likelihood ratio tests for testing if a sample has a categorical or Bernoulli distribution. 
[G tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) are also likelihood ratio tests for testing if a sample has a specific distribution.
so my question is: do multinomial and binomial tests belong to G tests?

Thanks!

Comment: @Scortchi: yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are. In particular, take a look at the formula on that page for the multinomial test where it refers to the likelihood ratio test, a few lines down from the top. The $x_i$ there is the same as the $O_i$ on the G^2 test, and if you consider the $pi_i$ equal to $O_i/n$, and the $p_i$ equal to $E_i/n$, then you'll see that it is precisely the G Test.